# Show Local Network Privacy Dialog

Tags: swift, swiftui, local-network

Is there any way to present again Local Network Permission dialog when user already **denies** access?
I am able to trigger this dialog **first time**, but if user later **disables the permission** to Local Network, **I want to present again this dialog**.

***P.S :** **I saw apps that do this, so it is possible somehow...***

[image]

Comment: You can’t, you can make your own message and route the user to settings but you can’t send the message twice. This is the same for any permissions in iOS. The user has to delete the app or reset settings for permission to be called again.

Comment: @loremipsum is this the case now?  Originally there was no API specifically to ask for local network permission and some of the hacks people used to trigger it were reported as being repeatable even if permission was initially denied.  (not used it since it first came out so this is hearsay).  It's definitely the case for the more established permissions with mature APIs.

Comment: I am sure that there is a way to ask again, because I have apps that do this.

Answer (score 0):

@lorem ipsum was right, there is no possibility to ask again for permission. The app I had with this feature just imitated the permission dialog, but when you taped on OK, I was redirected to Device settings menu.